# error while loading shared libraries: unexpected reloc type 0x7e

Tags: linux, types, mips, shared

I build embedded linux 2.6.32 with mips glibc compiler.
A lot of application can not run. They all display this error message.
I can not find the string "error while loading shared libraries" and
"unexpected reloc type" in the linux source code. Where do they come from?

Is it the kernel problem or the library problem or the application problem?

Answer (score 1):

It could be related to incompatibility between the toolchains (compilers, linkers) used to build the applications. And in practice, MIPS don't mean much: there are different [MIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture) architectures with different instruction sets.

Comment: You are right. The problem is some application are build with libc-2.9.so, but the file system has only /lib/libc-2.7.so.

Answer (score 0):

That error message in particular comes from `/lib/ld-linux.so.2`, the dynamic linker.  I have no clue what's causing the error message, though.

Comment: Thanks. I found the string by "strings /lib/ld.so.1" because my system has only ld.so.1.